# To add background colour to table cell by taking color value from html and using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the html code used.

```
<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">
```

The colour value should be acquired from html and it needs to be used to apply colour to table cell using javascript. This is the javascript code.

```
let color_value = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
$('document').on('ready',function(){
  $('td').click(function(){
    let colour = $('#colorPicker');
    $(this).css("td.background-color","color_value");
  });
})
```

But the colour is not added to table cell when the cell was clicked. How to solve this?

Comment: Use `color_value` instead of `"color_value"` (the former is a variable, the latter is simply a string). Also, you might want to define `color_value` within the click event instead, since the input value might have been changed before the user clicks on the `<td>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code. Try this:

```js
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", $("#colorPicker").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">
<table>
    <td>text</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').on('ready',function(){
  //let color_value = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
  $('td').click(function(){
    let colour = $('#colorPicker');
    let color_value = colour.val();
    $(this).css("td.background-color",color_value);
  });
})
```